# How to install Zlib 1.2.12 version as it is not available in apt package manager?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, update-alternatives, zlib

Zlib 1.2.11 version has been installed currently in my system but I need to upgrade it to 1.2.12. I tried to install via apt commands but apt doesn't have the 1.2.12 version. According to the apt  package manager 1.2.11 is the latest.

Comment: If you need cutting edge versions of software, maybe Ubuntu isn't the right distribution for you. You could consider compiling the latest version from source - either in the main distro, or inside a VM or container, depending on your usecase.

Comment: In addition, it seems some of the bugs fixed in 1.2.12 has actually also been fixed in the [latest Ubuntu version](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib_1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.1/changelog), so maybe you should be more clear about why you need 1.2.12 and not the security patched 1.2.11 currently present.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thank you for your response Artur. I would like to address the memory corruption issue CVE-2018-25032 (https://orca.security/resources/blog/zlib-memory-corruption-vulnerability-cve-2018-25032/). Has the zlib 1.2.11 version provided a patch for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu releases of `zlib` has patched known vulnerabilities. In particular, version `1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9` released on Fri, 25 Mar 2022 patched CVE-2018-25032, with the following [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib_1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.1/changelog):

> ```
> zlib (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9) jammy; urgency=medium
>
>   * SECURITY UPDATE: memory corruption when deflating
>     - debian/patches/CVE-2018-25032-1.patch: fix a bug that can crash
>       deflate on some input when using Z_FIXED in deflate.c, deflate.h.
>     - debian/patches/CVE-2018-25032-2.patch: assure that the number of bits
>       for deflatePrime() is valid in deflate.c.
>     - CVE-2018-25032
>
>  -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Fri, 25 Mar 2022 08:06:31 -0400
> ```